# How can I pass an argument to a keyfunc being passed to itertools.groupby?

Tags: python, python-itertools, functools

SO!

Here is a function using `itertoos.groupby`:

```
from string import whitespace, punctuation
from itertools import groupby

def tokenize(phrase, sepcat=True):
    separators = dict.fromkeys(whitespace + punctuation, True)
    return [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(phrase, separators.get)]
```

Right now, the output is as follows:

As you can see, consecutive separators are concatenated into a single string.  I would like this behavior to be optional (as denoted by the `sepcat` parameter to my function), but this  is where I hit a roadblock... How can I pass parameters to `separators.get`?

Can something like `functools` help me here?

Comment: You can't do that with the recipe you're using - that's what groupby does - it groups runs of matching elements...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a lambda:

```
groupby(..., lambda x: my_normal_function(x, other, arguments))
```